# Paramiko Transport Stuck Thread with Multi-Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, paramiko

I applied connect try to connect over 500 machine SSH with Python Paramiko using multi-threading with setDeamon True and join with time out to handle stuck connections after connect about 50 -70 machine and close connections properly the paramiko transport connection stuck with some machines
<paramiko.Transport at 0x34d41130 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>
which causes system error can't start new threads after stuck threads reach over 500 thread
how can I close paramiko transport connection after thread timed out
'''python

def run_sub_list_thread(self):

```
        try:

            threads = []
            for machin_ip in node_sub_list:
               thread = Thread(target=self.foo, args=[machin_ip])
               
               thread.setDaemon(True)
               threads.append(thread)
               thread.start()
                    
               timeout = 60 * 20 / len(threads)
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join(timeout=timeout)
                    
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
            
        return 'yes', 'Success'


def _connect(self, machin_ip):
   
    _ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    _ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    
        
    try:


        _ssh_client.connect(
            machin_ip, port=22, username=password[0], password=''
        )

        
        _invoked_shell = (
            _ssh_client.invoke_shell()
        )
        self._invoked_shell = _invoked_shell
        t.sleep(2)

    except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
        exception_message = "Exception::{0}::{1}".format(method_name, e)
        print(exception_message)
        return "error", exception_message, None, None

    except Exception as e:
        exception_message = "Exception::{0}::{1}".format(method_name, e)
        print(exception_message)
        return "error", exception_message, None, None

    #Some code here to connect machine properly 
    
        self._ssh_client = _ssh_client
        self._working_username = _working_username
        self._working_password = _working_password
        return _status, _invoked_shell, _working_username, _working_password

    except Exception as e:

        exception_message = "Exception::{0}::{1}".format(method_name, e)
        print(exception_message)

        return "error", exception_message, None, None

def _disconnect(self):
    
    method_name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
    class_name = self.__class__.__name__
    
    try:
        self._invoked_shell.close()
        self._ssh_client.close()

        return 'yes', 'Connection Closed'
    except Exception as e:
        exception_message = f"Exception::{class_name}::{method_name}::{repr(e)}"
        print(exception_message)
        return 'error', exception_message
```

def foo(self,machin_ip):

```
    method_name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
    class_name = self.__class__.__name__
    
    try:
        self._connect(machin_ip)
        # sleep instead of run commands and processing commands output
        t.sleep(300)
        self._disconnect()

        return 'yes', 'Done'
    except Exception as e:
        exception_message = f"Exception::{class_name}::{method_name}::{repr(e)}"
        print(exception_message)
        return 'error', exception_message
```

'''

this code run on windows server 2016
Get error can't start new thread after stuck paramiko.transport threads reached over 500 thread

<paramiko.Transport at 0x34d41130 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please supply us with a bit more information, like your code, and the error message you're getting including its stack trace.  It might also help to know more about the environment you're running in.

Comment: If you're trying to implement that kind of scope, I would recommend looking at ansible or the older [fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/) over writing your own implementation in paramiko.